# apply condition on objects rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

```
node(:status) { @status }
node(:message) { @message }

object @patient
attributes :medication, :guardian_id, :id, :name, :email, :username, :address, :age, :gender

node :errors do |e|
e.errors
end
```

**I want something like this**

if object is patient

do this

eleif object is doctor

do this

**How to apply condition in rabl file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rabl`, you would just use normal `Ruby` for if-statements.

```
if !@patient.nil?
  # do this
elsif !@doctor.nil?
  # do that
end
```

I didn't know how you intended to use your objects, just guessed. Could also be something like `if object == 'patient'` etc...